# Unity C# StartCoroutines - is it possible to put a string into the StartCoroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm using StartCoroutines in a different class, problem is I need the class its calling to be dynamic. `LevelSelected = "Camera.GetComponent<Level"+levelnumber+">().Pattern1()";`

LevelSelected is a string,the levelnumber is the level(int), and I'm wanting it to pick up the enumerator functions from that class. Level number is decided by whichever level the player picks on the start menu.

Problem I'm having is... if I output what I need into the string.

```
`StartCoroutine (LevelSelected);`
```

It errors out saying - Coroutine 'Camera.GetComponent().Pattern2()' couldn't be started! But when I hardcode this value in, it works fine...

is there a way around this??

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Reading between the lines, do you have a different behavior for each level? `Level1`, `Level2`, and so on? That's not a good idea. Also, note on the [`StartCoroutine` docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) that you can only pass a method name, not a C# expression (what you're trying to pass).

Comment: Yeah I get that, I'm just wondering if theres a workaround - I can literally just hardcode in what the string says and it works..

There is level 1,level2 etc but the levels are all the same.

Comment: Have you tried this?
`LevelSelected = "Camera.GetComponent<Level" + levelnumber.ToString("d0") + ">().Pattern1()";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you are performing an illegal action right there 
GetComponent<> can only use direct references to class names.
Instead of trying to throw in the value within the string, do something like this :

```
var levelScript = Camera.GetComponent<Level>();
StartCoroutine(levelScript.Pattern(levelnumber));
```

And in your pattern function change it to something like this

```
IEnumerator Pattern(int levelnumber)
{

}
```

Comment: hey man, LevelSelected = "Camera.GetComponent<Level"+levelnumber+">().Pattern2()";

was the error, sorry copied from the error log.. problem is the string I'm using can't be called in the StartCoroutine because its another string...

I can get it working otherwise just wondering if I can use a string as the value to be put into a Coroutine...(instead of the Ienumeration name)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you want to give a string when starting the routine use this: IEnumerator Pattern(string levelnumber)

Comment: I just realised you're are trying to call multiple functions from a string.. No you can't do this.

Comment: yeah problem seems to be I cant use a string as the methodname in the Coroutine even if it is the same value..